# Array of first-class functions as an instance variable in Swift

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, first-class-functions

I experience the following problem trying to create a variable that stores an array of functions:

```
class MySwiftClass {

    // Compilation Error: '()' is not a subtype of 'MySwiftClass'
    var arrayOfFunctions: [() -> Int] = [myFunction] 

    func myFunction() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Actually this code cannot be compiled with error:

> '()' is not a subtype of 'MySwiftClass'

But it works if setup this array in runtime:

```
class MySwiftClass {
    var arrayOfFunctions: [() -> Int] = [() -> Int]()

    init() {
         arrayOfFunctions = [myFunction]
    }

    func myFunction() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain whether it's a bug of Swift compiler or it's expected behaviour? I don't see any reason for compilation error in the first case, moreover error description is meaningfulness as for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by design in Swift. A initializer assigned to a property (in your case, `arrayOfFunctions`) cannot access `self` before `init` is run. In  your case, it's trying to access `self.myFunction`. You can only access `self` safely in the `init` method.

Look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html at "Safety Check 4".

Answer (score 0):

As @tng stated, that is correct, and I would like to propose a solution, which is using a static method, like this:

```
class MySwiftClass {


    var arrayOfFunctions: [() -> Int] = [MySwiftClass.myFunction]

    static func myFunction() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```